# Fragment getChildFragmentManager() api level < 17

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am very new to Android programming and I was wondering how I am able to fix this error that I'm getting. I have scowwered the internet searching for solutions on how to compensate for the fact that I have api 15 instead of the required 17 for my FragmentTransaction. I tried importing the support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction but still no luck here is the code:

```
    package com.hfad.workout;

    import android.os.Bundle;

        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
        import android.app.Fragment;

        public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
            private long workoutId;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                if(savedInstanceState != null)
                {
                    workoutId = savedInstanceState.getLong("workoutId");
                }
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                StopwatchFragment stopwatchFragment = new StopwatchFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.stopwatch_container, stopwatchFragment);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
            }
         }
```

Any reason as to why the `support.v4.app` might not be working? Is there a work around to this? Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: You've got the wrong `Fragment` class imported. It should be `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, not `android.app.Fragment`. If you're using support `Fragment`s, all of the `Fragment`-related classes need to come from the support packages.

Comment: Thanks very much that did the trick VERY well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use `"import android.app.Fragment"` for your fragment.That's why your `support.v4.app`not working here.
Try to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` for using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Correct! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can try to chaging from

```
    import android.app.Fragment;

    public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
```

to

```
    import android.support.v4.app;

    public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
```